# Python regular expressions not recognizing \number

Tags: python, regex

The following expression in my python interpreter (version 3.2.3):

```
re.compile('([0-9])\1')
```

Is failing to match strings like '11' or '77'. I was told on multiple occasions that `\number` would refer to the expression surrounded by the `number`th parenthesis, so why wouldn't this regular expression match?

Comment: You need to use a raw string: `r'([0-9])\1'`

Comment: A that was the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape the backslash (`\`)

```
re.compile('([0-9])\\1')
```

or use raw string literal:

```
re.compile(r'([0-9])\1')
```

Otherwise, `\1` matches a character `\x01`, and not match previous group number 1.

```
>>> re.search('([0-9])\1', '55')
>>> re.search('([0-9])\1', '5\x01') # '5\x01' == '5\1'
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f3a86ef8120>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match integers, you can use:

```
re.compile('[0-9]*')
```